# Format data long to wide across values with NA

Tags: r, tidyr, spread

I'm converting an [r](/questions/tagged/r) [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe) from long to wide format, with `NA` values. And trying to add new rows that perform operations that "skip" the `NA` values.

I can use `spread()`, but ultimately want to perform operations on each measurement that is collected across multiple years. In the example below, this may contain two or more values. For example `meas == 4` contains three values, where the other measurements contain two:

```
df <- data.frame(meas=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4), 
             year=rep(c("y2016", "y2017","y2018")), 
             value=c(1,2,NA,NA,1,4,1,NA,3,1,5,10))

spread(df, year, value)
  meas y2016 y2017 y2018
1    1     1     2    NA
2    2    NA     1     4
3    3     1    NA     3
4    4     1     5    10
```

What I'm ultimately looking for is something between a long and a wide dataset, as shown here:

```
  meas year1 year2 value1 value2
1    1  2016  2017      1      2
2    2  2017  2018      1      4
3    3  2016  2018      1      3
4    4  2016  2017      1      5
5    4  2017  2018      5     10
```

Comment: Do you need `dcast(setDT(df), meas ~ rowid(meas), value.var = c('year', 'value'))`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to pivot the `data.frame`, using `lead` thoughtfully should suffice:

```
df %>%
  mutate(year = stringr::str_extract(year, "[0-9]+")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  group_by(meas) %>%
  mutate(year2 = lead(year),
         value2 = lead(value, order_by = year)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value2)) %>%
  select(meas, year, year2, value, value2)

# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   meas [4]
   meas year  year2 value value2
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1 2016  2017      1      2
2     2 2017  2018      1      4
3     3 2016  2018      1      3
4     4 2016  2017      1      5
5     4 2017  2018      5     10
```